# Do i just have to start again?

Tags: data-structures, module, linked-list

Put it to me plain and simple please. I was trying to implement a circular doubly linked list with a sentinel node and came up with some higher or lower game that goes backward and forwards and loops through the players. It works fine.... Except I realise i had to have two separate files for the ring module (a .h and a .c) and then a separate main file. The code is long and i have't tidied it up after i realised my mistake as it would be pointless. So im not asking you to read it or check for mistakes or anything. But if you can tell me on a scale of 1-10 how bad the situation is by just skimming over it, i would be very grateful. Just so i can get my head around the scale of what im going to have to do... thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#define PLAYERLIMIT 5

//Doubly linked list implementation
struct Node {
    char data[20];
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};
struct Node* sentinel; //global pointer to the sentinel node
struct Node* head;
struct Node* tail;

// Create sentinel node, originally it just points to itself

struct Node* MakeSentinel () {
struct Node* SentinelNode =
(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
SentinelNode->next = SentinelNode->next;
SentinelNode->prev = SentinelNode->prev;
return SentinelNode;
}

//Creation of a node takes an int and returns a node
struct Node* GetNewNode (char *x) {
    struct Node* newNode =
    (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); //created node in the dynamic memory
strcpy (newNode->data, x); //temp->data is same as (*temp).data
newNode->prev = NULL;
newNode->next = NULL;
return newNode;
}

//Returning a pointer to newly created node, inserts next to sentinel
void InsertAtHead (char *x){
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
if (sentinel == NULL) {
    sentinel = MakeSentinel();
    head = newNode;
    sentinel->next = head;
    sentinel->prev = head;
    head->next = sentinel;
    head->prev = sentinel;
    return;
}
head->prev = newNode;
newNode->next = head;
newNode->prev = sentinel;
sentinel->prev = newNode;
head = newNode;
}

void PrintHead() {
//    printf("Sentinel prev is %s\n", sentinel->prev->data);
struct Node* temp = sentinel->prev;
printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
printf("The players in the game are\n\n");
while (temp != sentinel) {
    printf ("%s ", temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;

}
printf("\n");
printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
}

//Removing a name from the linked list
void DeleteEntry (struct Node* del) {
    if ((del->next != sentinel) && (del->prev != sentinel)) {
del->next->prev = del->prev;
del->prev->next = del->next;
}
else if (del->next == sentinel) {
    del->next->next = del->prev;
    del->prev->next = del->next;
}
else if(del->prev == sentinel) {
    del->next->prev = del->prev;
    del->prev->prev = del->next;
}
//    printf("Sentinel prev is now%s\n", sentinel->prev->data);

return;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

//Entering all player names into the doubly linked list
printf ("Enter the names of the players. Press Enter after each new player\n");
printf ("Must have 5 Players'.'\n\n");

int i = 1;
char name[20];


while ((i <= PLAYERLIMIT)) {

    printf("Player: ");
    scanf ("%s", name);
    InsertAtHead(name);
    i++;

}
PrintHead();

//Starting the Game

//Initialising Variables for the game
int nextCard;
int currentCard;
int score;
char oppositeGuess[20];
int userChoice;
int playGame = 1;
struct Node* CurrentPlayer = head;
struct Node* PlayerBefore;

//Setting up the random cards
int range;
srand(time(NULL));
range = (13 - 1) + 1;

nextCard = rand() % range + 2;
currentCard = rand() % range + 2;

while (playGame == 1) {

    //Change current card to past card before creating a new current card
    currentCard = nextCard;

    //generate a random int for card

    nextCard = rand() % range + 2;

    if (currentCard < 11) {
        printf("\nThe current card is a %d.\n", currentCard);
    }
    else if (currentCard == 11) {
        printf("\nThe current card is a jack.\n");
    }
    else if (currentCard == 12) {
        printf("\nThe current card is a queen.\n");
    }
    else if (currentCard == 13) {
        printf("\nThe current card is a king.\n");
    }
    else if (currentCard == 14) {
        printf("\nThe current card is an ace.\n");
    }

    printf ("***%s it is your go!***\n", CurrentPlayer->data);
    if (CurrentPlayer->prev != sentinel) {
        PlayerBefore = CurrentPlayer->prev;

    }
    else {
        PlayerBefore = sentinel->next;

    }
//        printf("\nThe CurrentPlayer is %s\n", CurrentPlayer->data);
//        printf("The PlayerBefore is %s\n\n", PlayerBefore->data);
    printf("Will the next card be higher(1) or lower(2)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &userChoice);
    printf("\n");
    printf ("***%s would you like to guess the opposite?***\n", PlayerBefore->data);
    scanf("%s", oppositeGuess);
    if (strncmp(oppositeGuess, "Yes", 4) == 0) {

        if (userChoice == 1) {
            if (currentCard < nextCard) {
                printf("\nSorry, %s was correct. You are out!\n", CurrentPlayer->data);
//                    printf ("\n IM GONNA DELETE %s\n", PlayerBefore->data);
                DeleteEntry(PlayerBefore);

            }
            else if (currentCard > nextCard) {
                printf ("Congratulations! player %s was wrong and is now out!\n", CurrentPlayer->data);
//                    printf ("\n IM GONNA DELETE %s\n", CurrentPlayer->data);
                DeleteEntry(CurrentPlayer);

            }
            else if (currentCard == nextCard){
                printf("\nCards were equal. Next players turn.\n");
            }
        }
        else if (userChoice == 2) {
            if (currentCard < nextCard) {
                printf("Congratulations! player %s was wrong and is now out!\n", CurrentPlayer->data);
//                    printf ("\n IM GONNA DELETE %s\n", CurrentPlayer->data);
                DeleteEntry(CurrentPlayer);

            }
            else if (currentCard > nextCard) {
                printf ("\nSorry, %s was correct. You are out!\n", CurrentPlayer->data);
//                    printf ("\n IM GONNA DELETE %s\n", PlayerBefore->data);
                DeleteEntry(PlayerBefore);

            }
            else if (currentCard == nextCard){
                printf("\nCards were equal. Next players turn.\n");
            }
        }
    }
    if (strncmp(oppositeGuess, "No", 4) == 0) {

        if (userChoice == 1) {
            if (currentCard > nextCard) {
                printf ("\nSorry you have guessed incorrectly, you are out!\n");
//                    printf ("\n IM GONNA DELETE %s\n", CurrentPlayer->data);
                DeleteEntry(CurrentPlayer);

            }

            else if (currentCard < nextCard) {
                printf("\nCongratualtions you were correct, next players turn.\n");
            }
            else if (currentCard == nextCard) {
                printf("\nThe cards are the same. Next players turn.\n");
            }
        }
        else if (userChoice == 2) {
            if (currentCard > nextCard) {
                printf ("\nCongratualtions you were correct, next players turn.\n");

            }
            else if (currentCard < nextCard) {
                printf("\nSorry you have guessed incorrectly, you are out!\n");
//                    printf ("\n IM GONNA DELETE %s\n", CurrentPlayer->data);
                DeleteEntry(CurrentPlayer);


            }
            else if (currentCard == nextCard) {
                printf("\nThe cards are the same. Next players turn.\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("\nPlease enter a valid choice.\n");
        }
    }

        PrintHead();
    if (CurrentPlayer->next != sentinel) {
        CurrentPlayer = CurrentPlayer->next;
    }
    else {
        CurrentPlayer = sentinel->prev;
    }

    if ((CurrentPlayer->next == sentinel) && (CurrentPlayer->prev == sentinel)) {
        playGame = 0;
    }
}
printf("%s you are the Winner!\n", CurrentPlayer->data);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you'll need to start again: you can use this as an opportunity to refactor and test your code.

Answer (score 0):

On a scale of 1-10 I think this code is worth saving: you've taken a fairly tedious exercise (making a circular list) and turned it into something fun.

There's no problem with having separate files for different modules, you can include them with a `#include` command. For example if you put all the linked list stuff in `mydllist.c`

```
//Doubly linked list implementation
struct Node {
  char data[20];
  struct Node* next;
  struct Node* prev;
};

struct Node* sentinel; //global pointer to the sentinel node
struct Node* head;
struct Node* tail;

// Create sentinel node, originally it just points to itself

struct Node* MakeSentinel () {
  struct Node* SentinelNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  SentinelNode->next = SentinelNode->next;
  SentinelNode->prev = SentinelNode->prev;
  return SentinelNode;
}

//Creation of a node takes an int and returns a node
struct Node* GetNewNode (char *x) {
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); //created node in the dynamic memory
    strcpy (newNode->data, x); //temp->data is same as (*temp).data
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

//Returning a pointer to newly created node, inserts next to sentinel
void InsertAtHead (char *x){
    struct Node* newNode = GetNewNode(x);
    if (sentinel == NULL) {
      sentinel = MakeSentinel();
      head = newNode;
      sentinel->next = head;
      sentinel->prev = head;
      head->next = sentinel;
      head->prev = sentinel;
      return;
    }

 head->prev = newNode;
 newNode->next = head;
 newNode->prev = sentinel;
 sentinel->prev = newNode;
 head = newNode;
}

void PrintHead() {
//    printf("Sentinel prev is %s\n", sentinel->prev->data);
  struct Node* temp = sentinel->prev;
  printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
  printf("The players in the game are\n\n");
  while (temp != sentinel) {
    printf ("%s ", temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;

  }
  printf("\n");
  printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
}

//Removing a name from the linked list
void DeleteEntry (struct Node* del) {
    if ((del->next != sentinel) && (del->prev != sentinel)) {
      del->next->prev = del->prev;
      del->prev->next = del->next;
    }
    else if (del->next == sentinel) {
      del->next->next = del->prev;
      del->prev->next = del->next;
    }
    else if(del->prev == sentinel) {
      del->next->prev = del->prev;
      del->prev->prev = del->next;
    }
    //    printf("Sentinel prev is now%s\n", sentinel->prev->data);

    return;
}
```

You can include it at the top of the dllist_game.c file like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "mydllist.c"
```

I'd then start by doing some simple refactorings, particularly of your main() function, to make your code easier to understand.

Along with your `#define PLAYERLIMIT 5` I'd add a `#define NUMBER_OF_CARDS 13` (or whatever the max number of cards is) along with an enum type for boolean values

```
typedef enum {true, false} bool;
```

That way when you define range instead of writing:

```
int range;
srand(time(NULL));
range = (13 - 1) + 1 //n.b. (13 - 1) + 1 = 13 is there some reason you wrote it like this?
```

You can write

```
int range = NUMBER_OF_CARDS;
srand(time(NULL));
```

It always a good idea to initialise variables to a default value: you might forget they're uninitialised and try to use them (which can potentially be bad):

```
int nextCard = 0;
int currentCard = 0;
int score = 0;
char oppositeGuess[20] = "";
int userChoice = 0 ;
bool playGame = true;
struct Node* CurrentPlayer = head;
struct Node* PreviousPlayer = head->prev;
```

I'd change the name of the loop counter from `i` to `num_entered_players`, so it's easier to see what the variable is for when it's in use:

```
int num_entered_players = 1;
char name[20];

while ((entered_players <= PLAYERLIMIT)) {
    printf("Player: ");
    scanf ("%s", name);
    InsertAtHead(name);
    num_entered_players++;
}
```

Finally I'd start extracting parts of the big `while` loop into smaller functions, which describe what's going on. For example the lines:

```
if (currentCard < 11) {
    printf("\nThe current card is a %d.\n", currentCard);
}
else if (currentCard == 11) {
    printf("\nThe current card is a jack.\n");
}
else if (currentCard == 12) {
    printf("\nThe current card is a queen.\n");
}
else if (currentCard == 13) {
    printf("\nThe current card is a king.\n");
}
else if (currentCard == 14) {
    printf("\nThe current card is an ace.\n");
}
```

would become:

```
void printCurrentCard(int currentCard){

  if (currentCard < 11) {
        printf("\nThe current card is a %d.\n", currentCard);
    }
    else if (currentCard == 11) {
        printf("\nThe current card is a jack.\n");
    }
    else if (currentCard == 12) {
        printf("\nThe current card is a queen.\n");
    }
    else if (currentCard == 13) {
        printf("\nThe current card is a king.\n");
    }
    else if (currentCard == 14) {
        printf("\nThe current card is an ace.\n");
    }   
}
```

and would be called like this:

```
while (playGame == true) {

    //Change current card to past card before creating a new current card
    currentCard = nextCard;

    //generate a random int for card
    nextCard = rand() % range + 2;

    printCurrentCard(currentCard);

....
}
```

etc. So if you change the rules of the game in a particular step, there's only one place you'll need to change the code - and it shouldn't affect the rest of the game.

Once you've done these changes - the logic of your game can go into another pair of .c and .h files and you can call it directly from a separate main()!